# OAuth: Do I need to HMAC-SHA1 encrypt over HTTPS

Tags: security, twitter, oauth

When using OAuth and using TLS, do I still need to do all that ordering, concatenating and signing of the oauth_ params or is it considered secure already?

Thanks, Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes it is secure, but the oauth 1.0 spec still requires it. OAuth 2.0 does not require it, but it is optional and is used for a [mac access token type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-00). It all depends on what the service provider supports.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 seems to support this idea, and Twitter is not yet on it.